# C++ Template type inside a structure

Tags: c++, templates, struct

Here is my MESSAGE structure:

```
struct tEventMessage 
{
    // Type of the event
    int Type;

    // (void*) Allows those to be casted into per-Type objects
    void *pArgument1;   
    void *pArgument2;

};
```

Can i add some kind of 'template' member to this structure, so that later on when building message i can pass those pointers + and any other data i wish ? ( see example below )

```
struct tEventMessage 
{
    // Type of the event
    int Type;

    // (void*) Allows those to be casted into per-Type objects
    void *pArgument1;   
    void *pArgument2;

    // Template
    T tSomeTemplateMember;
};

 void HandleClick(....)
 {
 CVector3 vNewPosition = ....

 tEventMessage _msg;
 _msg.Type = xxxx;
 _msg.pArgument1 = pA->GetObjectPointer();

 //
 // Wrong!
 // Because this CVector3 will not be alive in next tick
 // - my pointer will point to nothing.
 //
 _msg.pArgument2 = static_cast<CVector3*>(&vNewPosition)


 //
 // Something like that would be great
 // And would allow me to use CVector2,CVector3,CVector4 with one template member
 // 
 _msg.tSomeTemplateMember = vNewPosition;

 }
```

Comment: Just use polymorphism properly.

Comment: Why don't you create inherited classes for your messages, and not have a struct with a type identifier? It would be much more resilient, and you wouldn't have to deal with this mess.

Comment: @Xymostech never thought about that this way.. that's a damn good advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're over complicating the problem. Instead of one problem, how to pass arbitrary data in a message, you now have two, how to cope with templates as well.

The usual method to implement this sort of thing is to use inheritance:-

```
class Message
{
public:
  int Type () { return type; }
protected:
  int type;
};

class ClickMessage : public Message
{
public:
  ClickMessage () { type = ClickMessageID; }
private:
  // the message data
};

void HandleMessage (Message *message)
{
  switch (message->Type ())
  {
  case ClickMessageID:
    HandleClick (reinterpret_cast <ClickMessage *> (message));
    break;
  default:
    // unhandled message error
    break;
  }
}

void HandleClick (ClickMessage *message)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

The problem is you end up repeating a lot of code, i.e the cast in the switch statement. There's also a maintenance issue too - added new messages requires a bit of careful updating. You could hack the code a bit and use function pointers and a map to convert message types to functions and replace the switch statement.

There might be a clever template solution, but I can't think what it might be.

Using RTTI might help (at a cost).

This is one problem that reflection is really good at solving!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I am missing something however I am wondering why you do not start with an abstract class from which you then derive your various kinds of event messages.  By taking advantage of abstract classes and deriving classes from them, you let the compiler figure out the logic that you are using a switch statement for.  See this [C++ Polymorphism and Abstract Base Class tutorial](http://www.codingunit.com/cplusplus-tutorial-polymorphism-and-abstract-base-class).

Also see this from [MSDN on Abstract classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8whxhf1.aspx).

For instance you might have an abstract class that looks like the following.  However you may not want as much of this and in fact may just want the single `processEvent()` method only.  Any derived classes will need to provide their own versions of each of the functions specified in the abstract class.

```
class EventMessage abstract {
public:
    virtual void *getArgument1 (void) = 0;
    virtual void *getArgument2 (void) = 0;
    virtual int   processEvent (void) = 0;
protected:
    void *pArgument1;
    void *pArgument2;
};
```

What this abstract class defines is a class that basically contains the data that is used by  all of the various event messages along with a method that is called to process the the actual message.  The class itself is not instantiated however it is used as the parent or super class for other derived class that are actually instantiated as objects.

What you would then do is to derive new classes that would implement the EventMessage interface.  For instance here are two different classes that would do that:

```
class JoJoEvent : public EventMessage {
public:
    JoJoEvent(void *arg1, void *arg2);
    void *getArgument1 (void);
    void *getArgument2 (void);
    int   processEvent (void);
};
JoJoEvent::JoJoEvent(void *arg1, void *arg2)
{
    pArgument1 = arg1;
    pArgument2 = arg2;
}

void * JoJoEvent::getArgument1 (void) {
    return pArgument1;
}
void * JoJoEvent::getArgument2 (void) {
    return pArgument2;
}

int JoJoEvent::processEvent (void) {
    // do stuff with the arguments
    return 1;
}

class KoKoEvent : public EventMessage {
public:
    KoKoEvent(void *arg1, void *arg2);
    void *getArgument1 (void);
    void *getArgument2 (void);
    int   processEvent (void);
};
KoKoEvent::KoKoEvent(void *arg1, void *arg2)
{
    pArgument1 = arg1;
    pArgument2 = arg2;
}

void * KoKoEvent::getArgument1 (void) {
    return pArgument1;
}
void * KoKoEvent::getArgument2 (void) {
    return pArgument2;
}

int KoKoEvent::processEvent (void) {
    // do stuff with the arguments
    return 1;
}
```

Then when using these you would do something like the following code:

```
EventMessage *myMessage = new JoJoEvent(0, 0);

EventMessage *myMessage2 = new KoKoEvent(0, 0);

myMessage2->processEvent();
myMessage->processEvent();
```

If you need to add additional data into the derived classes you can do so just provide a mechanism to put the data into the derived class.